# Serial Port not detecting using Java

Tags: java, serialization, serial-port, serial-communication

I am trying to connect to my serial port "COM6", but now I cannot connect to it. I tried printing out the list of serial ports available using `portId.getName()`. It shows a list of serial ports available but COM6 is not showing there.

This is my Java code:

```
portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
        portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
            if (portId.getName().equals("COM6")) {
            //if (portId.getName().equals("/dev/term/a")) {
                try {
                    serialPort = (SerialPort)
                    portId.open("Arduino", 2000);
                } catch (PortInUseException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error1 is "+ e);
                }
                try {
                    outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error2 is "+ e);
                }
                try {
                    serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,
                        SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                        SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                        SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error3 is "+ e);
                }

                try{
                    byte data1 = 1;
                    outputStream.write(data1);
                    System.out.println("helo");
                    System.out.println(data1);

                }catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.println("Error 3: " + e);
                }

            }

        }
    }
    serialPort.close();
```

I have checked the COM6 in my device manager. It shows available. If I run the same com port in vb it works perfectly. Can anyone help me with this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to communicate with an Arduino? If so, you have to install the [Arduino IDE](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software) - there is also the RXTX library included, which is very similar to the Java Communication API. 
Then you can try this code, which is very similar to yours:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;  
import gnu.io.SerialPort;  
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent; 
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener; 
import java.util.Enumeration;


public class SerialTest implements SerialPortEventListener {
    SerialPort serialPort;
    /** The port we're normally going to use. */
    private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = { 
        "/dev/tty.usbserial-A9007UX1", // Mac OS X
                    "/dev/ttyACM0", // Raspberry Pi
        "/dev/ttyUSB0", // Linux
        "COM3", // Windows
};
/**
* A BufferedReader which will be fed by a InputStreamReader 
* converting the bytes into characters 
* making the displayed results codepage independent
*/
private BufferedReader input;
/** The output stream to the port */
private OutputStream output;
/** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
/** Default bits per second for COM port. */
private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

public void initialize() {
            // the next line is for Raspberry Pi and 
            // gets us into the while loop and was suggested here was suggested http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=32186
            System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", "/dev/ttyACM0");

    CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
    Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
    while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
        CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
        for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
            if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                portId = currPortId;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (portId == null) {
        System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
        return;
    }

    try {
        // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                TIME_OUT);

        // set port parameters
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

        // open the streams
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
        output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

        // add event listeners
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
}

/**
 * This should be called when you stop using the port.
 * This will prevent port locking on platforms like Linux.
 */
public synchronized void close() {
    if (serialPort != null) {
        serialPort.removeEventListener();
        serialPort.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and print it.
 */
public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        try {
            String inputLine=input.readLine();
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
    // Ignore all the other eventTypes, but you should consider the other ones.
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SerialTest main = new SerialTest();
    main.initialize();
    Thread t=new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            //the following line will keep this app alive for 1000 seconds,
            //waiting for events to occur and responding to them (printing incoming messages to console).
            try {Thread.sleep(1000000);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
        }
    };
    t.start();
    System.out.println("Started");
}
```

}

The code comes from the [Arduino Playground](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Java), I'm not able to try it out now, but I connected an Arduino two or three months ago with this code (Windows 8, 64Bit). There are also other methods described in the post, as well as all necessary requirements (e.g. classpath variables) - check them out in your system setting.

Hope it helps.